# Cannot connect to Tomcat's MBeanServer via jconsole in Java6

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, administration

I'm on a vista machine. I've started tomcat 5.5.27 with these options:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9003 \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

When I connect via jconsole and added the following service url

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9003/jmxrmi
```

it would not connect. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I orignally supposed the URL given by op was wrong but it turns out no. So I can't answer.

Still, here are the basics:

For a simple connection through `jconsole`.

If you **know** that the JMX Server you want to connect to has the *RMI registry port* at 9003 for example, connect using

```
localhost:9003
```

instead.

Otherwise, here's what I found out from the ground up:

Suppose you have the JMX Server (alias 'JMX Agent' alias 'the JVM you want to connect to') running on 'TARGET MACHINE' with the *RMI registry port* at 'RMI REGISTRY PORT' and the *JMX RMI server port* at 'JMX RMI SERVER PORT'.

Note:

1. The *RMI registry* tells JMX clients where to find the *JMX RMI server port*; information can be obtained under key `jmxrmi`.
2. The *RMI registry port* is generally known as it is set through system properties at JVM startup.
3. The *JMX RMI server port* is generally **not** known as the JVM chooses it at random (if no other precautions are taken).

The following URI will lead to success (tested)

`service:jmx:rmi://<TARGET_MACHINE>:<JMX_RMI_SERVER_PORT>/jndi/rmi://<TARGET_MACHINE>:<RMI_REGISTRY_PORT>/jmxrmi`

This looks nasty. Let's cut it apart.

This URI is an RFC2609 "Service Location Protocol URL" (well, it's really an URI, right?)

It is composed of:

- `service` - a constant
- `jmx:rmi` - the *service type* composed of: *abstract type* `jmx` and *URL scheme* `rmi`
- the rest  - the *sap* (service access protocol specification)

*sap* is decomposed into:

- `//<TARGET_MACHINE>:<JMX_RMI_SERVER_PORT>` - ipsite
- `/jndi/rmi://<TARGET_MACHINE>:<RMI_REGISTRY_PORT>/jmxrmi` - URL part

A well-informed JMX client connects to the "ipsite" to do JMX-over-RMI exchanges; but what of the JMX client that doesn't KNOW that port? Patience...

*URL part* is decomposed into:

- `/jndi/` - This seems to tell the JMX client that it can get lookup information at the location that follows
- `rmi://<TARGET_MACHINE>:<RMI_REGISTRY_PORT>/jmxrmi` - Yep, we get information about the JMX RMI Server at the RMI registry, under the lookup key `jmxrmi`

This is somewhat cart-before-horse, as one has to contact the *RMI registry* given by the **latter** part of the SLP URL first.

After scratching head, intuitively, let's try:

`service:jmx:rmi://<TARGET_MACHINE>/jndi/rmi://<TARGET_MACHINE>:<RMI_REGISTRY_PORT>/jmxrmi`

Yes, that works! The JMX RMI server port is nicely obtained from the registry. On second thoughts, the *target machine* should also be obtained from the registry, thus:

`service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<TARGET_MACHINE>:<RMI_REGISTRY_PORT>/jmxrmi`

Even better, that works, too!

References:

```
1 download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/remote/rmi/package-summary.html
2 download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXServiceURL.html
3 mx4j.sourceforge.net/docs/ch03s04.html
4 download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdevg
5 http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2609.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 10.04, using OpenJDK 6 and Tomcat 6.0.29, I was unable to activate JMX for a local jconsole session, no matter how many **com.sun.management.jmxremote.*** options I passed to java with CATALINA_OPTS. The problem was the **-Djava.io.tmpdir** setting, which defaults to **$CATALINA_BASE/temp**. I simply had to set:

```
CATALINA_TMPDIR="/tmp"
```

at the beginning of *bin/catalina.sh* and I was able to connect locally with jconsole, jmap, jps etc. There was no need for any **com.sun.management.jmxremote.*** settings at all.

Comment: This did not work for me, i still receive the same error. In any case, glad it helped you, but I am wondering the intuition behind why this works.  Perhaps this idea can be extended...

Answer (score 1):

Are the processes run under the same user?

You can also check by running jps and jconsole (both in the JDK_HOME/bin directory)

Answer (score 0):

This is also needed for OS X 10.7 aka Lion.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question here:[java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685686/java-rmi-connectexception-connection-refused-to-host-127-0-1-1)

I found many of the Q&A on this topic, not nothing was helping me - that's because my issue was more basic ( what can I say I am not a networking guru :) ).  My ip address in /etc/hosts was incorrect.  What I had tried included the following for CATALINA_OPTS:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128M -server 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7091 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=A.B.C.D"  #howeverI put the wrong ip here!

export CATALINA_OPTS
```

My problem was that I had changed my ip address many months ago, but never updated my /etc/hosts file.  it seems that by default the jconsole uses the hostname -i ip address in some fashion even though I was viewing local processes.  The best solution was to simply change the /etc/hosts file.

The other solution which can work is to get your correct ip address from /sbin/ifconfig and use that ip address when specifying the ip address in, for example, a catalina.sh script:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=A.B.C.D
```