# Explain JMX URL

Tags: java, jmx

I am trying to understand a JMX service URL.

```
service:jmx:rmi://192.168.30.10:1234/jndi/rmi://192.168.30.10:2344/jmxrmi
```

It would be great, if someone can help me understand this.

Thanks

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743343/cannot-connect-to-tomcats-mbeanserver-via-jconsole-in-java6

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I will reuse an answer I wrote up earlier for this question: [Cannot connect to Tomcat's MBeanServer via jconsole in Java6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743343/cannot-connect-to-tomcats-mbeanserver-via-jconsole-in-java6)

It's not complete, but might help:

Suppose you have the JMX Server (alias 'JMX Agent' alias 'the JVM you want to connect to') running on 'TARGET MACHINE' with the *RMI registry port* at 'RMI REGISTRY PORT' and the *JMX RMI server port* at 'JMX RMI SERVER PORT'.

Note:

1. The *RMI registry* tells JMX clients where to find the *JMX RMI server port*; information can be obtained under key `jmxrmi`.
2. The *RMI registry port* is generally known as it is set through system properties at JVM startup.
3. The *JMX RMI server port* is generally **not** known as the JVM chooses it at random (if no other precautions are taken).

The following URI will lead to successful connection (tested)

`service:jmx:rmi://<TARGET_MACHINE>:<JMX_RMI_SERVER_PORT>/jndi/rmi://<TARGET_MACHINE>:<RMI_REGISTRY_PORT>/jmxrmi`

This looks nasty. Let's cut it apart.

This URI is an RFC2609 "Service Location Protocol URL" (well, it's really an URI, right?)

It is composed of:

- `service` - a constant
- `jmx:rmi` - the *service type* composed of: *abstract type* `jmx` and *URL scheme* `rmi`
- the rest  - the *sap* (service access protocol specification)

*sap* is decomposed into:

- `//<TARGET_MACHINE>:<JMX_RMI_SERVER_PORT>` - ipsite
- `/jndi/rmi://<TARGET_MACHINE>:<RMI_REGISTRY_PORT>/jmxrmi` - URL part

A well-informed JMX client connects to the "ipsite" to do JMX-over-RMI exchanges; but what of the JMX client that doesn't KNOW that port? Patience...

*URL part* is decomposed into:

- `/jndi/` - This seems to tell the JMX client that it can get lookup information at the location that follows
- `rmi://<TARGET_MACHINE>:<RMI_REGISTRY_PORT>/jmxrmi` - Yep, we get information about the JMX RMI Server at the RMI registry, under the lookup key `jmxrmi`

This is somewhat cart-before-horse, as one has to contact the *RMI registry* given by the **latter** part of the SLP URL first.

After scratching head, intuitively, let's try:

`service:jmx:rmi://<TARGET_MACHINE>/jndi/rmi://<TARGET_MACHINE>:<RMI_REGISTRY_PORT>/jmxrmi`

Yes, that works! The JMX RMI server port is nicely obtained from the registry. On second thoughts, the *target machine* should also be obtained from the registry, thus:

`service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<TARGET_MACHINE>:<RMI_REGISTRY_PORT>/jmxrmi`

Even better, that works, too!

References:

1. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/remote/rmi/package-summary.html
2. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXServiceURL.html
3. http://mx4j.sourceforge.net/docs/ch03s04.html
4. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdevg
5. http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2609.txt

Answer (score 11):

To explain:

```
service:jmx:rmi://192.168.30.10:1234/jndi/rmi://192.168.30.10:2344/jmxrmi
```

1. `service:jmx:rmi://192.168.30.10:1234` - says that there is a JMX Agent on the machine with IP address 192.168.30.10. The JMX agent is using (TCP) port 1234 to provide JMX service(s) over RMI (basically acts as an RMI server).
2. `/jndi/rmi://192.168.30.10:2344/jmxrmi` - says that the RMI stub to interact with the JMX Agent over RMI can be found in the RMI registry which is running on the machine with IP address 192.168.30.10 and is using (TCP) port 2344. To get the RMI stub you need to lookup the "jmxrmi" binding.

Previous answers suggest that the 2nd part of the URL is to obtain the server port of the JMX RMI server. That is not correct. The JMX RMI server port is (TCP) 1234 and is part of the URL. What you get from the RMI registry is the RMI stub (`javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub`) which you can use to talk to JMX Agent (MBean Server) over RMI.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since you are stating that the answer by @david-tonhofer isn't correct, can you please explain how the URLs without the 1st IP:port pair (`192.168.30.10:1234` in this example) function?  i.e., the URLs that start with `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi:`.   Part of the reason this is so confusing in general is that when we specify a jmx port while starting the JVM, it doesn't reference RMI anywhere: `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=2344`.  (Note that in my experience that jmxremote port is associated with the "RMI Registry" portion of the URL, not the "JMX RMI Server" portion.)

Comment: There are a number of ways to specify the IP and port that the JMX agent will use. If you wish to fix it to a specific IP and address you can use `service:jmx:rmi://192.168.30.10:1234`. Alternatively you can use `com.sun.management.—` properties. 
Use an URL such as `service:jmx:rmi:///…` to let Java pick the IP and port for you (randomly or based on system properties). 
Use an URL such as `service:jmx:rmi://0.0.0.0:1234` to bind port 1234 on all interfaces.
And so on. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

According to [javax.management.remote.rmi](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/remote/rmi/package-summary.html)

this url is assembled like this

```
service:jmx:rmi://ignoredhost/jndi/rmi://myhost/myname
```

Comment: i think he is asking why it needs to be so complex.