# Required information for jConsole or jVisualVM to make a remote connection

Tags: java, jvm, jconsole, jvisualvm, heap-dump

I am in the process of setting up remote connections for JVM analysis. 
The connection screens for jconsole or jvisualvm ask for below usage information.

> usage: **hostname**:**port**  OR service:jmx:**protocol**:**sap**
>
> **variables** are in bold

My questions are
1) For **hostname:port**
the port number corresponds to which process. (I think it might be jmx.) And how to setup this process on the server(test, prod) or developer machines.

2) For service:jmx:**protocol**:**sap**
what is the protocol. And what all protocols are possible.
And what is sap?

Comment: For `hostname:port`, the port is the one you configured on the remote process, e.g. by providing `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1234` at startup. For `service:jmx:` URIs there are several variants. If there is a rmiregistry running with default settings, the simplest? form is: `service:jmx:rmi://hostname`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552960 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768087

Comment: @Holger, that really answers. For (2) the protocol seems to be used in an unusual way i.e host:port is something unusual as protocol. Any way that answers. And does **sap** stand for something?