# How to configure JDK8 JMX port to allow VisualVM to monitor all threads

Tags: jboss, java-8, jvm, jmx, visualvm

I need to monitor a JDK 8 JVM on a production Red Hat 6 Linux server that allows me no direct access.  I'm able to connect to the JMX port using VisualVM.

I can see the Monitor tab: CPU usage; heap and metaspace; loaded and unloaded classes; total number of threads.

However, I can't see dynamic data on the Threads tab.  It shows me total number of threads and daemon threads, but no real time status information by thread name.

I don't know how to advise the owners of the server how to configure the JDK so I can see dynamic data on the Threads tab.

It works fine on my local machine.  I can see the status of every thread by name, with color coded state information, if I point VisualVM to a Java process running locally.

What JVM setting makes dynamic thread data available on the JMX port?

Update:

I should point out that I'm using JBOSS 6.x.

If I look at my local JBOSS 6.x standalone.xml configuration I see the following subsystem entry for JMX:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
        <expose-resolved-model/>
        <expose-expression-model/>
        <remoting-connector/>
    </subsystem>
```

I can see all dynamic thread information when running on my local machine.

I'm asking the owners of the production instance if the standalone.xml includes this subsystem.  I'm hoping they will say that theirs is different.  If it is, perhaps modifying the XML will make the data I need available.

Comment: by far have no idea what is going on, but may be adding the visualvm version would help?

Comment: JDK 8 and JBOSS 6 ought to be sufficient.

Comment: did you use JMX URL to connect to the remote java pid? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768087/explain-jmx-url explains the syntax part.

Comment: Yes.  Like I said, I can see the monitor tab perfectly.  i want the threads tab to be displayed as well, but configuration is preventing it.

Comment: Do you see CPU information in Monitor tab?

Comment: Yes, I do.    Please read the post: "I can see the Monitor tab: CPU usage; heap and metaspace; loaded and unloaded classes; total number of threads."