# java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1;

Tags: java, exception, connection, rmi, remoteobject

```
    java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:128)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.notifyMe(Unknown Source)
    at CallbackServerImpl.doCallback(CallbackServerImpl.java:149)
    at CallbackServerImpl.registerForCallback(CallbackServerImpl.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 23 more
```

I get this exception when I try to connect a remote client to my server. In both, server and client the hostName for the registryUrl of rmi is the public IP address of the server. I also tried to put localhost in server but the error doesn't change.

My java.policy is set to grant all connections to all ports and I have no firewalls enabled in the server or the client.

Any suggestions what could be?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is [item A.1 in the RMI FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#domain). You need to either fix your /etc/hosts file or set the `java.rmi.server.hostname` property at the server.

Comment: Please, how are you rsolved this problem ? i try with: java HelloServer -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.5
but the client cant' find the server  java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée

Comment: @researcher You have to set it at the server JVM. Not the client.

Comment: @researcher And you also have to provide JVM arguments before the class name, not afterwards.

Comment: the 'server' is the skeleton side on which the stub was originally created via .export; on the server side modify the implicitly stub embedded ip the client invokes: `System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","1.2.3.4");` meaning this is the ip the destination/skeleton/server is approachable

Comment: @PatrickBucher The person you mention only contributed a question. You should be thanking is me.

Answer (score 21):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I had exactly the same error. When the remote object got binded to the rmiregistry it was attached with the loopback IP Address which will obviously fail if you try to invoke a method from a remote address. In order to fix this we need to set the **java.rmi.server.hostname** property to the IP address where other devices can reach your rmiregistry over the network. It doesn't work when you try to set the parameter through the JVM. **It worked for me** just by adding the following line to my code just before binding the object to the rmiregistry:

`System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","192.168.1.2");`

In this case the IP address on the local network of the PC binding the remote object on the RMI Registry is 192.168.1.2.

Comment: It *does* work when you 'try to set the parameter through the JVM', by which you presumably mean on the command line. If you use `System.setProperty()`, you have to set it before exporting the remote object, not just before binding.

Answer (score 13):

you can use `LocateRegistry` such as:

```
Registry rgsty = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1888);
rgsty.rebind("hello", hello);
```

Comment: He is not getting an eror on `rebind()`.

Comment: I was using the Naming.rebind() method before and got a similar error posed above. I changed it and followed your code suggestion, added the port number in my Naming.lookup(), my problem is then fixed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lucky This answer does not suggest `Naming.lookup()`.

Answer (score 9):

I found many of the Q&A on this topic, not nothing was helping me - that's because my issue was more basic ( what can I say I am not a networking guru :) ).  My ip address in /etc/hosts was incorrect.  What I had tried included the following for CATALINA_OPTS:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128M -server 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7091 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=A.B.C.D"  #howeverI put the wrong ip here!

export CATALINA_OPTS
```

My problem was that I had changed my ip address many months ago, but never updated my /etc/hosts file.  it seems that by default the jconsole uses the hostname -i ip address in some fashion even though I was viewing local processes.  The best solution was to simply change the /etc/hosts file.

The other solution which can work is to get your correct ip address from /sbin/ifconfig and use that ip address when specifying the ip address in, for example, a catalina.sh script:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=A.B.C.D
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're running in a Linux environment, open the file `/etc/hosts.allow`
add the following line

```
ALL
```

## [Wildcards](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2005/10/using-tcp-wrappers-to-secure-linux.html)

Also check the `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/host` to see if there might be something wrong there.

I had to change my `/ etc / host` from

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 AMK
```

to

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 AMK
```

also wrote in `ALL` in the file `/etc/hosts.allow` which was previously completely empty

## Now everything works

do not know how safe it is. you have to read more about possible options for `/etc/hosts.allow` to do something that requires a touch of security.

Comment: Thanks, I just modify /etc/hosts to point my localhost and hostname to the same ip, as you show, and now all works

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your rmiregistry not be created before client trying connect to your server and it would lead to this exception.In Linux, you can use "netstat" to check your rmiregistry be bond on the right port you assigned in java code.

Comment: It wouldn't cause this exception with this stacktrace.

Comment: Oh but it would, observing it on my Archlinux box now. Creating the registry with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099)` in my server class rather than getting it with `LocateRegistry.getRegistry()` solves the problem for me.

Comment: It solves another problem. It solves 'connection refused' *when doing the lookup*. This problem is 'connection refused' *when calling the remote method*.

Answer (score 2):

If you've tried modifying etc/hosts and adding java.rmi.server.hostname property as well but still registry is being bind to 127.0.0.1

the issue for me was resolved after explicitly setting System property through code though the same property wasn't picked from jvm args

Comment: The Registry does not get bound to 127.0.0.1  If the system property didn't work from the command line you did it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me after getting rid of "::1" in /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem and my issue was that I had 2 IP addresses from 2 different networks configured in the etc/hosts as below.

```
10.xxx.x.xxx    localhost
192.xxx.x.xxx   localhost
```

This should be because there was a conflict as to which IP to be used for the other devices to reach the rmiregistry over the network.

Once I removed the extra-record that is not required, I was able to solve the issue.

So my etc/hosts file had only the following record.

```
10.xxx.x.xxx    localhost
```

Comment: They're both wrong. Those IP addresses should both map to a real hostname, and there should be another entry `127.0.0.1 localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

### IntelliJ

I used these flags in IntelliJs *VM Options* to enable IPv6 only support, which lead to this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: ::1; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect in ExceptionUtil.rethrow(ExceptionUtil.java:138) Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: ::1; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:626) at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:217) at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:204) at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:344) at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:116) in RemoteProcessSupport.lambda$acquire$2(RemoteProcessSupport.java:324) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:593) at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583) at java.base/java.net.Socket. (Socket.java:507) at java.base/java.net.Socket. (Socket.java:287) in RemoteServer$1.createSocket(RemoteServer.java:156) ... 22 more Suppressed: com.intellij.database.util.AsyncTask$Companion$FrameData: Async frame data: Submit -> Prepare connection ->
```

I commented the flags out with a `#`

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true
```

And started the postgres server via

```
postgres -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data"
```

Answer (score -1):

when you want to connect to remote server with **RMI** you must add a system property same as:

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","Ip or DNS of the server");
```

or add environment variable.

For me I got **Connection Refused** and solve it by adding this line of code in server side:

```
 java -jar -Djava.rmi.server.hostname="ip or dns of the server" packageName.jar
```

Thank to other guy for guide me to solve it.

Comment: There is no 'must' about it. It's only necessary with misconfigured DNS, or in some multi-homed host situations.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows make sure your Windows firewall is correctly configure / disabled. I had to disable the Windows firewall (because I didn't bother with configuring it) to get things to work even when I was testing with localhost.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was unable to edit the hosts file because using a pc from the university.

I fixed the problem running rmiregistry in another port (instead of 1099) with:

```
rmiregistry <port>
```

and then running the server on that port.

It was basically an error caused by occupied port.

Comment: If the port was already occupied you didn't get 'connection refused', and changing the Regsitry to another port didn't fix anything unless you also adjusted the code, and port 1099 was reserved for the RMI Registry by 1996, so whatever alleged process was allegedly already listening to it was severally non-compliant.

Answer (score -1):

When I got the same error on my machine ("connection is refused"), the reason was that I had defined the following on the server side:

```
 Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:8080/AddService"
   ,addService);
```

Thus the server binds both the IP = 127.0.0.1 and the port 8080.

But on the client side I had used:

```
AddServerInterface st = (AddServerInterface)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost"
                        +"/AddService");
```

Thus I forgot to add the port number after the localhost, so I rewrote the above command and added the port number 8080 as follows:

```
AddServerInterface st = (AddServerInterface)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:8080"
                        +"/AddService");
```

and everything worked fine.

Comment: This is not correct. The URL you use for the Registry does not determine what IP address the remote object is bound to. The IP bind has already happened prior to this code.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use:

on server side:

```
Registry <objectName1> = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
Registry <objectName2> = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
```

on Client Side:

```
Registry <object name you want> = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This doesn't answer the original question.