# property server.rmi.localhostname on jmeter version 2.13

Tags: jmeter, rmi

I have set up jmeter distributed testing using my local machine (master) and AWS EC2 machines (slaves). Most of the config is based on - http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2012/02/16/how-to-run-jmeter-over-ssh-tunnel/

When running tests I have following exception on jmeter-server.log

```
2015/11/06 12:42:37 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.RemoteTestListenerWrapper: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is:
```

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

One possible solution I came across is from one of the stackover flow question-

- [java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685686/java-rmi-connectexception-connection-refused-to-host-127-0-1-1)

and I indeed start my server as -

```
./jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
```

and it did not solve the problem. Few other blogs talk about setting following property on server -

```
server.rmi.localhostname=127.0.0.1
```

But I can not find any such property on jmeter 2.13
Was this property removed or replaced by some other property ?

Comment: I added the property server.rmi.localhostname in jmeter.properties file and error I mentioned above disappeard. 
I also had to specify -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 on jmeter master node. Though I am curious to know why property server.rmi.localhostname is missing from jmeter.properties file

Comment: why -1, what is wrong with question ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem and just came across this question. If you click on the link that leads to the [original blog posts](http://developersblog.espris.sk/2009/10/how-to-jmeter-ssh-tunnel.html) it mentions the following:

> WHAT THE PATCH DOES
>
> - Adds jMeter parameter server.rmi.localhostname - jMeter by default 1) binds to the host's hostname and 2) refuses to bind to localhost. If this parameter is set, jMeter will bind to the specified ip/hostname and (only if this parameter is set) won't complain even if it is localhost.

I assume this patch never made it into JMeter itself. At least for me, just adding the property in question doesn't seem to make it work.

Comment: Since I posted this question I got disillusioned of using distributed mode of testing as it has impact on throughput you can achieve with it. Since then I have started using - https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2

or a modified version (for Jmeter 2.13) - 
https://github.com/TestingForum/jmeter-ec2

(Still a work in progress)

And I get far better throughout then what I do with distributed testing