# RMI Server on Unix machine

Tags: java, rmi

I have an RMI server and RMI client programs, when I execute RMI server on unix machine, and RMI client on Windows machine, I am getting

> java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused to host: ; nested exception is:   java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: connect   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)

at the client side. I am able to execute on server and client on windows system but the server on linux is not working.

I searched using google, but I am unable to find the reason and fix.

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the host name resolve?

Comment: I am able to resolve the host.

Comment: You are *not* able to resolve the hostname. That's what the exception means.

Answer (score 0):

Referring the url 
[java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685686/java-rmi-connectexception-connection-refused-to-host-127-0-1-1)
I added a line to /etc/hosts file and it works, but I am accessing the host using the IP address in my client program.

I did not understand why do we need to add a line to the /etc/hosts file.

Any comments. Thank You!.

Comment: You have to do it so that the target hostname can be resolved. Obviously. You've already been told that.